# Raster: how to locate cells having nodata

Tags: raster, oracle-spatial

I am new to oracle spatial. I am using SDO_GEOR package's getNoData prcedure. the results are populated in following format. MDSYS.SDO_RANGE(MDSYS.SDO_RANGE(-32768,null))

My questions are:

1. Is result an array object / just a some form specification ?
2. if an object how can I use / consume it further say to generate a list/ array of cell coordinates.

My main intention is to locate the cells having nodata from the oracle( original raster file had nodata / voids cells).

I am not a GIS/ spatial pro.

Query:
select SDO_GEOR.getNODATA(georaster, 0 ) from <> where id=<>

Answer (score 1):

The SDO_GEOR.getNODATA() function does not extract the NODATA cells. What it does it to show you how the NODATA cells are identified, i.e. the value, or range of values (or even multiple ranges possible) that identify a NODATA cell.

You can achieve what you want using the Raster Algebra mechanism. Among other things that lets you select cells from a raster that match any algebraic expression.

Read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/GEORS/geor_raster_algebra.htm#GEORS1215

Comment: thanks much Albert!, unfortunately i am working with 11g+ and sdo_geor_ra package is not avaible in this version. Anyways thanks for your reply. Can't up the vote as not having enough points.